# An exit condition for a do-while loop using lists in C#

Tags: c#

I have an integer list, `l`, and a predefined integer value row (which is never manipulated inside the code). If value of row is 5, then I want the loop to exit if `l` contains 1, 2, 3, and 4 or if it is 3 then `l` should contain 1 and 2 and so on for any value.

I have devised a way to do this, but since I mean to use this in an application, what is a better way to do the following?

```
do
{
}while(check(row, l))

boolean check(int row, list<int> l)
{
  for(int i=1; i<row; i++)
  {
    if((l.contains(i))
      continue();
    else
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: More suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you looking for a better way to control the loop exit or a better way to search if the row contains the element you are searching for?

Comment: check seems to be another method. So he wants to have the method to instruct the while loop to `break` basically. Which is not possible

Comment: The most efficient/least time complex way

Comment: What do you want to do exactly in your do-while loop ? if you can provide us more information about what are you trying to achieve then we can suggest you for better way

Comment: As has been mentioned, this question is about improving working code and thus belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Depending on the size of `l` you may want to turn the list in to a `HashSet<int>` before you do your loop (if `l` changes inside the `while` loop you would need to do it inside `check` however if `l` stays the same you could do it before the `while` loop for even more speed savings). If the list is large you may get a significant boost.

Comment: Please post the contents of your while loop - it's impossible to determine whether your code can be improved without seeing its contents. For example; is `i` incremental in each `while` iteration? Is `l` variable on each `while` iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if your list contains all numbers from 1 to (row-1), you could use a `HashSet` like this:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(myList.Where(item => item >= 1 && item < row))
```

This adds all "relevant" items of the list to the Set.

Since a `HashSet` contains every item at most once, you can check the `Count` of it to ensure, all numbers are present, like:

```
var check = hashSet.Count == (row - 1)
```

Regarding performance, this might be more efficient than your solution, since the list needs only to be iterated once (in your solution, you have `row-1` iterations, one for every `Contains` operation). And adding to a `HashSet` is considered a O(1) operation.

Note: The major drawback of this solution is that its not immediately apparent what it does. So consider adding a comment to it.

Another, more readable approach would be to explicitely check, if all numbers are contained in the Set, like

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(myList);
var check = Enumerable.Range(1, row).All(number => hashSet.Contains(number));
```

If you consider `row` to be a constant the asymptotical time will be the same: O(n) for constructing the `HashSet`, and O(1)*O(1)=O(1) for the check itself (first O(1) for the constant number of "rows" to be checked, second O(1) for the `Contains` function...)

Comment: Adding to the set is a O(1) but the constructor you are using is O(n) where n is the size of the list you put in. Still giving a +1 though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "the list needs only to be iterated once". You will not be able to get less than O(n), since (in the worst case) you'll have to scan the list until its end. Depending on the structure of the list, you might be able to get better "best case" or "average case" results, if you do an explicit loop for constructing the HashSet and break it as soon as the set reaches a Count of `row-1`...

Comment: There is no non-generic `HashSet`, there is only the generic `HashSet<T>`, is that what you meant?

Comment: @svick Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks, I've edited the answer.